# Javascript \x escapes within a mixed string

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I have a string that I got by using Ajax to load a preview of a web page. The title comes out like this:

`You Can\xe2\x80\x99t Handle the Truth About Facebook Ads, New Harvard Study Shows`

I need to replace those escape codes with human readable text. I have tried `String.fromCharCode()`, but that doesn't return anything in the case of a mixed string, only if you send it character codes only.

Is there a function I can use to fix this string?

Comment: What exactly is the content that the ajax is loading? And what is the ajax code? Usually it should resolve escape characters when parsing the content already.

Comment: That looks really weird... those are hex escapes but printing the string gives me goobledegack. Why would you need 3 hex bytes for an apostrophe?

Comment: @JaredSmith Fancy Unicode apostrophe in UTF-8?

Comment: @melpomene In that case, I would consider the encoding of the string to be broken though. The string should be `can\u2019t`.

Comment: Briefly, here is the Ajax code:     $("#id_url_text").on('input propertychange paste', function(){
     $.ajax({
         url:'/webproxy/?q=' + $("#id_url_text").val(),
         type:'get',
         dataType:'html',
         crossDomain:true,
         success:function(data)
        {
   //var _html= jQuery(data);
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML = data;
   var titleSuggest = div.querySelector("meta[property='og:title']").getAttribute("content");
        },

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const str_orig = 'You Can\\xe2\\x80\\x99t Handle the Truth About Facebook Ads, New Harvard Study Shows';

console.log("Before: " + str_orig);

const str_new = str_orig.replace(
    /(?:\\x[\da-fA-F]{2})+/g,
    m => decodeURIComponent(m.replace(/\\x/g, '%'))
);

console.log("After: " + str_new);
```

The idea is to replace `\x` by `%` in the string (which produces a URL encoded string), then apply `decodeURIComponent`, which handles UTF-8 decoding for us, turning `%e2%80%99` into a single character: `’` (U+2019, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK).

Comment: @Bergi How would you use `String.fromCharCode` here?

Comment: `replace(/\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/gi, (_, c) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c, 16)))`

Comment: @Bergi Exactly. `\xe2\x80\x99` needs to turn into one character.

Answer (score 0):

Melpomene had the answer above, I just wanted to add one additional snip here: The above solution left an occasional \ or \n for some cases, so I modified it like this:

```
titleSuggest.replace(/(?:\\x[\da-fA-F]{2})+/g, m =>
decodeURIComponent(m.replace(/\\x/g, '%'))).replace(/\\n/g,
'<br>').replace(/\\/g, '')
```